# Images not displaying properly on Safari

Tags: html, css, safari

I've come across an issue that seems to be unique to Safari based on my testing. Upon loading the page images are displayed with a width of 100px and only revert to the specified width when the browser window is adjusted. Hoping for some clarity on this issue, thanks in advance!

```css
.mentor-box img {
  height: 365px;
  width: 250px;
}
```

```html
<div class="mentor-box">
  <img class="align-self-end" src="/imgs/some-image.png" alt="">
  <div class="align-self-center mentor-text">
    <p>Text here...</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: probably something to do with being a direct child of a flex container (I'm guessing mentor box is flex as you have align self classes on the children) - try wrapping it in a span or div

Comment: This fixed the issue! Thanks for your response